# Android Media player not playing next stream

Tags: android, stream, mp3, media-player

I currently have a media player which streams a mp3 and on completion should go to the next url. However, it is not playing. Am I doing something wrong? I originall have the urls in a string array but changed it and still does not work. It times out and the force closes.

code:

`try {
            houseMediaPlayer.setDataSource(housePlaylistString[0]);
            houseMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            houseMediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`

```
    `houseMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            try {
                houseMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24535120/Reminded%20-%20Tyga%20ft.%20Adele.mp3");
                houseMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                houseMediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            houseMediaPlayer.start();

        }

    });`
```